# Type hint for a function that returns only a specific set of values

Tags: python, python-3.x, type-hinting, literals, python-typing

I have a function that can only return `a`, `b` or `c`, all of them are of type `T`. I want to include this fact in the signature because of the special meaning they carry in the context of the function. How do I do that?

Currently, I use this

```
def fun(...) -> "a or b or c":
    #briefly explain the meaning of a, b and c in its docstring
```

Is that the correct one?

I know that I can do this

```
def fun(...) -> T:
    # briefly explain the meaning of a, b and c in its docstring
```

but as I said, I want to express in the signature that the function only returns those specific values.

Comment: Why not create an enumeration of those specific values and then specify that the type of return is that enumeration?

Answer (score 92, accepted):

## You can do that with [literal types](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/literal_types.html).

```py
from typing_extensions import Literal
# from typing import Literal  # Python 3.8 or higher

def fun(b: int) -> Literal["a", "b", "c"]:
    if b == 0:
        return "a"
    if b == 1:
        return "b"
    return "d"
```

mypy is able to detect the `return "d"` as a invalid statement:

```
error: Incompatible return value type (got "Literal['d']",
expected "Union[Literal['a'], Literal['b'], Literal['c']]")
```

### Python 3.8

Thanks to the [PEP 586](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0586/), the `Literal` is [already included](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/typing.html#typing.Literal) by default in the Python 3.8 `typing` module.

Comment: While this is a perfectly valid solution in many cases, I'd like to point to the avid reader that  Blckknght's answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/39398431/1394590) is in many cases the better approach, as it delegates the literal values to an enum, thus avoiding duplication (between signature and implementation), staying more flexible (you can add values without changing the signature), and making the function easier to consume (e.g. you can compare against an enum).

Answer (score 18):

You can't specify that your function returns only a subset of a type's values using type hinting alone. As the name implies, type hinting is all about *types* not values.

However, you can create a new `enum.Enum` subtype that only has the values you're going to return and use it in the function. Then you can type hint that you're returning the enum type.

```
import enum

class cmp_results(enum.IntEnum):
    less = -1
    equal = 0
    greater = 1

def my_cmp_function(x, y) -> cmp_results:
    if x < y: return cmp_results.less
    elif x == y: return cmp_results.equal
    else: return cmp_results.greater
```

This may be overkill. Just hinting `int` as the return type (and documenting the specific values) is probably good enough.

Comment: I don't think this is overkill at all. On the contrary, this is one of the benefits of static type-checking: you can specify *exactly* what the function can return. The fact that `less`, `equal`, and `greater` are merely aliases of a handful of `int` values is an implemenation detail. (And the particular values chosen wouldn't matter either if you didn't want to take advantage of the negative/zero/positive partition already supported by the `int` type.)

Comment: this enum idea look interesting, and it have the added bonus that I can do shenanigans with it to manipulate the output when called help on it for a nice documentation

Comment: @Copperfield You might want to consider accepting Cesar his answer with Literal types, which seem to be a new and better option.

Comment: @IvoMerchiers I'd say this is better than hardcoding the values into the `Literal` hint.

Answer (score 0):

If all are of the same exact type just *add that as the return type*:

```
def func(...) -> T: # or int or whatever else
```

> I want to express in the signature that the function only return those specific values

Type hints don't specify a name or a value they just specify a *type*; a type checker tries to *act* on the *type* that's provided.

If you're just doing this for documentation purposes, add `'a or b or c`' to it if you want; users will understand it but type checkers *won't* and they definitely won't act on it.

Comment: *all of them are of type `T`*

Comment: all of them are of the same type, for example the function only return  `1` or `-1` or `0`

Comment: @Jim -- unfortunately, that isn't something that's possible to do with PEP 484 type annotations. Within Python's gradual type system (and most type systems, for that matter), you can only add annotations stating that you are going to return a value of a particular _type_ -- it's not possible to restrict the output _value_ of a type. There _are_ type systems that let you do this (e.g. [dependent types](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependent_type)), but PEP 484 currently does not support dependent types.

Comment: This might be OK if `T` has so many values as to make enumerating them prohibitive (such as if you wanted a type of all positive integers, or all strings with length < 5), but for such a small enumerated type, there's no reason not to define the type explicitly.

Comment: @Michael0x2a aren't we saying the same thing? The gist of my answer was that this isn't something type hints do in python. The enum solution was a lovely one but other than that there's no way to indicate a specific value as a return type.

Comment: @Jim: hmm, I'm not sure now -- maybe I'm misinterpreting what you meant by your first comment? I'm saying that it's currently not possible to create a type that says "this value is an int, but can only be the values 1, -1, or 0". It seemed based on that comment that you were saying otherwise -- perhaps I was wrong about that?

Comment: @Michael0x2a probably you were, my comment was made when I misunderstood the question and proposed a `Union` solution. We're on the same page here.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense -- I didn't see the original version of your post. In that case, you're right, we're in agreement here -- apologies for misunderstanding :)