# Unpacking an iterable into subscript/a type hint?

Tags: python, python-3.x, type-hinting

Say I need a list of values both at runtime and as type hint:

```
from typing import Literal

valid_values = ('foo', 'bar', 'baz')

def f(arg: Literal[???]):
    assert arg in valid_values
```

Is it possible to unpack `valid_values` into the `Literal` type hint somehow, e.g. `Literal[*valid_values]` (which is invalid syntax)? Repeating the values would be sub-optimal.

Comment: Seems like the arguments to `Literal['foo', 'bar', 'baz']` are collected in the `__args__` attribute, so you could use `L = Literal['foo', 'bar', 'baz']` and then annotate with `def f(arg: L): ...` while using `arg in L.__args__` for the runtime check, but since `__args__` is a dunder attribute this availability might break without being deprecated.