# How do I use typing to force using a specific enum as an argument in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, enums, type-hinting, python-typing

I’m trying to write a function that would only except a specific enum that each value is a string so the function could not except a string but would get the wanted value from the enum

```
from enum import Enum

class Options(Enum):
    A = "a"
    B = "b"
    C = "c"

def some_func(option: Options):
    # some code
    return option
```

The problem I’m experiencing is that if I check the type I get this instead of a string:

```
>>> type(Options.A)
<enum 'Options'>
```

I would like to have it return this:

```
>>> type(Options.A)
<class 'str'>
```

Any idea how I can implement this so it would work the way I intended? Thanks in advance

Comment: I don't understand your question, or what you are even trying to accomplish. Why do you want `type(Options.A)` to return a string?

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/q/58521577/476

Comment: Are you looking for `Options.A.name` or `Options.A.value`? Those will get you the strings `"A"` and `"a"` respectively. I think explicitly using these fields are better alternatives to mixing in a str or doing `str(Options.A)` or whatever. Or alternatively, consider stopping using Enums altogether: the fact that they're normally distinct from strs or ints or whatever is supposed to be a feature. So if you're trying to circumvent that, Enums may not be the right tool for you to currently be using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
>>> type(Options.A)
```

is always going to return

```
<enum 'Options'>
```

because `Options.A` is an `<enum 'Options'>` member.  However, if you want

```
>>> isinstance(Options.A, str)
```

to be

```
True
```

then you need to mix in the `str` type:

```
class Options(str, Enum):
    A = "a"
    B = "b"
    C = "c"
```

---

**NB** *If you mix in the `str` type, then your `Enum` members become directly comparable with `str`*:

```
>>> Options.A == 'a'
True
```

Comment: Thank you, mixing worked for me. Would you mind replying why mixing worked or what is mixing specifically?

Comment: @JohnD:  `mixing` is just giving your (sub)class one more parent.  Originally, your `Options` class only had `Enum` for a parent (and so inherited `Enum` methods, properties, etc.), but when you mix-in, or add, `str` as a parent then your `Options` `Enum` also gets those properties, methods, etc., as well as also being that type.  For instance, `Options.A.upper() == 'A'` -> `True`.

Answer (score 0):

You can cast the value of the enum attribute:

```
from enum import Enum

class Options(Enum):
    A = "a"
    B = "b"
    C = "c"


str_enum = str(Options.A)
print(type(str_enum))
```