# How to write docstring in python to specify that a parameter can assume only a set of values

Tags: python, pycharm, docstring

Good morning everybody,

I need to know if there is a way, at the moment I say no, for having the behavior I write in JavaScript also in Python.

If in JavaScript, when I have a function with a parameter that can assume only some values, I write the following code

```
/**
 * Set the status of session
 * @param {('ACTIVE'|'LOCKED'|'UNAUTHORIZED')} status
 */
function set(status = 'UNAUTHORIZED') {
    console.log(status);
}
```

Writing in this way, calling the function makes my IDE (PHPStorm) to suggest me the list of values I can use as shown in the following image

[image]

This is my function in Python

```
def set(status: str) -> None:
    """
    Set the status of session

    :param status: ('ACTIVE','LOCKED','UNAUTHORIZED')

    :return:
    :rtype: None
    """
    print(status)
```

but I can't get the same result with IDE (PYCharm) probably because the syntax of docstring is wrong.

[image]

Is there a way to get in Python the same result I have in JavaScript?
For example, if I wrote the same function, how can I define the list of values that the parameter can assume?

Thanks to all of you

Comment: Not docstring, but actual type hinting: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58521635/476

Comment: @deceze already tried, but doesn't work as I'm expected.
```
from typing import Literal

def typed_method(parameter: Literal["value", "other value"]):
    pass

typed_method(parameter="valuessss") # "value" is not suggested
```

Comment: You mean PyCharm doesn't auto-complete the value for you? That's PyCharm's problem… The type hint works as is, and PyCharm even hints it properly, and it flags the call if you pass some other value. ‍♂️

Comment: [enum](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html) could be an alternative.

Comment: @deceze there is some specific configuration in PyCharm to get the behavior? Because in my version I can pass every value I want without getting suggestion

Comment: @Wups enum doesn't match my needs

Comment: Frankly, I don't think I've ever seen literal auto-completion in PyCharm [for Python code], so it might not exist at all…?