# Python type hint for variable of a specific type, from a specific class/enum

Tags: python, type-hinting, python-typing

Let's say I have a class with this two variables:

```js
class MyClass:
    FOO: str = "simple string 1"
    BAR: str = "simple string 2"

def myFunc(data: MyClass) -> MyClass:
    ...
```

I want to write a function `myFunc()` that accept one of the variables from `MyClass` (example: `FOO`) and return one of the variables of `MyClass` (example: `BAR`). I know what I want to be passed to this func - I know the types of these variables - so this function type hints could be also written as:

```js
def myFunc(data: str) -> str:
    ...
```

The problem here is that - although type checker is happy with it - user lost the important info of what are the possible values. What I want is that user know in this function can be passed only string, but must be from a specific class - in this case, I want user to pass a `str` value from class `MyClass`.

```js
def myFunc(data: SomeTypeHintSyntax[str, MyClass]) -> SomeTypeHintSyntax[str, MyClass]:
    ...
```

**Q: Is there a simple way to tell user where `data` of type `str` should come from?**

If type hint would suggest that `data` should come from `Myclass`, user can than use IDE to pass possible values by:
[image]

Comment: Why is ``MyClass`` not an ``enum.Enum`` subtype? Do you actually want people to use ``MyClass.FOO`` or ``"simple string 1"``?

Comment: Why *must* `data: str` come from the member of a specific class? And why must the *type checker* verify its origin?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Type hint for a function that returns only a specific set of values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39398138/type-hint-for-a-function-that-returns-only-a-specific-set-of-values)

Comment: @MisterMiyagi: I use enums where I want enums. Otherwise I use classes, since sometimes I need its __init__() method or other class functionality. Now, let's not go into how it should be and what I am doing wrong - because this (my) question is a tiny bite of a larger problem. Lets just say that I have classes with variables and I want to signify user that `data` of type `str` should actually be a value derived from specific class, in this example `MyClass`.

Comment: @MateenUlhaq For me it is good enough if type checker would report if anything else than `str` is given. Type-hinting `MyClass` is nice for user that doesn't need to leave IDE and check documentation, since it is recommended while typing...