# Python attribute type hint: list of specific strings?

Tags: python, type-hinting

Is there a type hint that expects a string out of a list of strings?

```
import typing

@dataclass
class Person:
   name: str = None
   gender: typing.Choice(['male', 'female'])  # <- Something like this?

Person(name='John', gender='male')   # okay
Person(name='John', gender='female') # okay
Person(name='John', gender='apple')  # error
```

Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Type hint for a function that returns only a specific set of values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39398138/type-hint-for-a-function-that-returns-only-a-specific-set-of-values)

Comment: @Georgy almost. I was looking for attribute hinting, not return hinting. At the end it's similar of course. Thanks for the link.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Multiple options:

- Based on typing (https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Literal, note: New in version 3.8.)

```py
from typing import Literal
gender = Literal['male', 'female', 'other']
```

- Using enums (https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html#enum.Enum)

```py
from enum import Enum
class Gender(Enum):
   FEMALE = "female"
   MALE = "male"
   OTHER = "other"
```