# How to use a certain set of values for typing in Python

Tags: python-typing

I need to specify a certain set of values as the expected return type for my function. Let's say there was defined some class called `Scene` which has attribute `name` which is supposed to be a string which may end only with `"1K"`, `"2K"` or `"4K"`. Now I want to write a function which takes this class as an argument and returns the last 2 characters of its name as a string. Is there a way to specify this function return type like a set of exact string values using **built-in** modules in Python 3.7.7? Something like this:

```
def scene_resolution(sc : Scene): -> any value in {'1K', '2K', '4K'}: # return type?
    res = sc.name[-2:]
    assert res in {'1K', '2K', '4K'}
    return res
```

I know about using [Literal from typing_extensions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57058709/14299556), but unfortunately it works only with Python 3.8 and higher, and the API of the soft I'm dealing with uses Python 3.7.7. I've also tried to make something with `enum.Enum` but could not make it work properly.

Do you have any suggestions?

**UPD.** The only way I found so far is to define some function that returns the set I need and use its name as expected return type. Not sure whether it is correct way and a good practice, but at least it works.

Comment: I don't know if you already tried this, but `Literal` should be available in `typing_extensions` for any version. Python 3.8 is the version it was added to the `typing` and it is backported to earlier versions through `type_extensions`. Its listed among the features for on the [typing_extensions GitHub](https://github.com/python/typing/tree/master/typing_extensions)

Comment: Thank you. I have tried to import it, but unfortunately built-in Python in the soft I'm dealing with doesn't include `typing_extensions` for some reason. At least I think I can copy the classes I need to define `Literal` class right out of the `typing_extensions` code directly into my script. It seems its License allows it.