# TypeScript vs. Python typing default arguments and autocompletion

Tags: python, python-typing

In TypeScript I used to have the following and it will work as type inference:

```js
function func(x: "#1" | "#2" | "#3" = "#2"): void {}
```

The above example should give you options and autocompletion when typing, and error when you type options that are not in the list of options.

When I was exploring Python I found the `typing` module. But what I tried didn't work, and I couldn't find what I've hopped to find.

My expected code:

```py
def func(x: "#1" | "#2" | "#3" = "#2") -> None:
    pass
```

My expected result should be similar to the one in TypeScript.

Comment: Are you looking for the equivalent of string literal types, in which case read e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/q/39398138/3001761, or something else?

Comment: Yes, just like the `Literal` there, just it didn't work with type hints on hover with vscode, and didn't give any options when writing, nor error when pass something invalid

Comment: Then that's a problem with PyLance or whatever VS Code uses. Mypy will flag it as an error.

Comment: Didn't expect that, but it's at least a good start for me, will see how that goes, thank you guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
from typing import Literal, TypeAlias


Valid: TypeAlias = Literal["#1", "#2", "#3"]


def func(x: Valid = "#2") -> None:
    print(x)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    func("#1")
    func("#2")
    func("#3")
    func("#4")
```

All valid, except the last line makes `mypy` rightfully complain:

```
error: Argument 1 to "func" has incompatible type "Literal['#4']"; expected "Literal['#1', '#2', '#3']"  [arg-type]
```

Note that in Python, the interpreter does not care about the type annotations and will execute that last function call without a problem.